# error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I added NGBootstrap in angular 5 project. But after sometime it's not working and I am getting below error. Tried to resolve issue by upgrading CLI version but still issue is not resolve. Please check package.json.

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(5,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'.
>   src/app/find-product/searchtabcontent/search-by-family/search-by-family.component.ts(2,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ng5",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod --base-href=/UI/pages/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1"
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you check those files are there in node_modules  folder?

Comment: Folder is there, tried to install ngBootstrap again but no luck.

Comment: Hvae you did the correct way https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Comment: Are you doing `NgbModule.forRoot()` on the import of your module root?

Comment: I installed NG-Bootstarp by following guidelines https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: @Malcor yes added that as well.

Comment: Did you import ng-boostrap into your app.module.ts ?

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake yes I import that.

Comment: Please edit your answer with a  copy/paste of your app.module.ts

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake Done.

Comment: Do you have another module than app.module.ts in your app ? If so, you must import NgbModule into them. If your search-by-family.component.ts is not dependent of app.module.ts, you must import the NgbModule into its module. @SantoshShelke

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake No I have only one module app.module.ts

Comment: i solved this issue by updating ng update @angular/core.Please try this

Answer (score 13):

If you have already tried to re `npm install` after deleting node_modules, the problem persists, and you also then double-checked that '@ng-bootstrap' is under your node_modules directory, I would proceed as follows:

- I would try first restarting the IDE, happens with Visual Studio Code and others as well...
- Also you could try this (this would be for linux):

  1. `sudo npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
  2. `cd @ng-bootstrap`
  3. `sudo npm install`
- Make sure, in case you have more than one module, that only the app.module has the import like `NgbModule.forRoot()`, any other module should only have `NgbModule` within the import []

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Working initially but after sometime again got the error.

Comment: did you also remove the package-lock.json?

Comment: No, it's there.

Comment: remove it as well before re install

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

**NG Bootstrap - Angular powered Bootstrap widgets**

`$ npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Angular widgets built from the ground up using only Bootstrap 4 CSS with APIs designed for the Angular ecosystem.

Below the list of supportive versions of Anuglar & Bootstrap :

**ng-bootstrap - Angular - Bootstrap CSS**

`1.x.x          5.0.2            4.0.0`

`2.x.x          6.0.0            4.0.0`

`3.x.x          6.1.0            4.0.0`

`4.x.x          7.0.0            4.0.0`

`5.x.x          8.0.0            4.3.1`

`6.x.x          9.0.0            4.4.1`

`7.x.x         10.0.0            4.5.0`

Comment: The source is missing

Answer (score 3):

you have juste to tape this commande:

```
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this method:
1. delete your module node folder then
2. delete your package-lock.json file
3. run npm install
4. run ng serve -o

This works for me, I hope you do too :)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened for me too.
I tried deleting node_modules folder and package-lock.json file
And tried all ways listed in forums.
Main issue was @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap was not listed in VSC as declarative.
Means it was not properly installed.
Hence i was not able to use the NgbModule.

This issue was resolved by excuting following comomands VSC terminal at angular project folder location:-

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

above command erred due to dependencies issue. i updated npm version

```
npm update  
npm version 
npm install --legacy-peer-deps @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm install --typesript@latest --save
```

above command is optional, you can skip, i did this as i found typescript version lower under vulnerabilities listing.

```
npm audit fix --force
```

finally i got @ng-bootstrap declarative in VSC.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by updating ng update @angular/core.Please try this

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone comes across this error.  I  tried all the answers, but what actually resolved it was closing VS Code and reopening.  To my surprise, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by following steps:

1. Check the angular version:
   Using command: ng version
   My angular version is: Angular CLI: 7.3.10
2. After that I have support version of ngx bootstrap from the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap
3. In package.json file update the version:
   "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
4. Now after updating package.json, use the command npm update
5. After this use command ng serve and my error got resolved

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing @ng-bootstrap. Please, tape this command:

```
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).